# try catch works well in Firefox but not in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, try-catch

Here is the fragment from my JavaScript code:

```
canRead=false;
try {
    d3.json(fileName, function(error, data) {
  });
  canRead=true;
}
catch(err) {
}
```

If the file does not exists canRead will remain false. In Firefox it works well but in Google Chrome canRead always becomes true and I get errors "net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND".

Comment: Why are you using `try/catch`? `json` method doesn't `throw` error, I'm not sure why Firefox catches an error. Check the passed `error` parameter.

Comment: @Vohuman It doesn't work in Firefox, it prints error "Access to restricted URI denied".

Comment: That's a HTTP error not a JavaScript error which is related to same-origin policy, According to my experience browser's JS interpreter doesn't `throw` a _JavaScript_ error for a _HTTP_ error.